# How can I upload Multipart Form Data with files by a parameter object in Alamofire above 5?

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I need to send Multipart Form Data with files(.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.txt) to the server. So
I have created a model for the data to be sent. My model looks like this:

```
struct CreateJobModel {
    let attachment:Data?
    let title:String
    let dscription:String
    let start_date:String
    let budget:String
    let city:String
    let zip:String
    let country:String
    let latitude:String
    let longitude:String
}
```

I also have a response object :

```
struct CreateJobResponseModel {
    let message: String
    let data:CreateJobUserData?
}
struct CreateJobUserData {
    let user_id:Int
    let type: String?
    let title: String?
    let description:String?
    let budget:String?
    let start_date: String?
    let city: String?
    let state: String?
    let zip: String?
    let country: String?
    let latitude: String?
    let longitude: String?
    let attachment: String?
    let id: Int
    let attachment_url: String?
    let start_date_timestamp: Int
    let service_details: String?
}
```

How can I send a multipart form data with files with Alamofire above 5?

Comment: That's too broad.  Nobody even knows what you have on the server side.

Comment: Can you tell me the basics that I can try?

Comment: I suppose I can, but why don't you ask Google, Yahoo or whatever about it without getting total strangers involved?

Comment: I have searched everywhere, I did not find anything suitable, Nothing with a model.